# \ref doesn't work in math mode if hyperref and bidi packages are loaded

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, cross-referencing, bidi

Is `\ref` supposed to work in math mode?  If `hyperref` and `bidi` are loaded, it generates errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}

Testing labels with \verb+hyperref+ and \verb+bidi+.

\section{This is a section}
\label{sec}

\begin{equation}
    a = b \label{eq} 
\end{equation}

In text mode everything works fine.  Referencing equation~\ref{eq} in section~\ref{sec}.

But if we try to do it in math mode, we get errors:  $\ref{eq}$

$\ref{sec}$

\[
\ref{eq}
\]

\[
\ref{sec}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: And is `\ref` -- which essentially returns a text-mode contents -- supposed to work in math mode?

Comment: @tohecz It does work if no extra packages are loaded.  Is that just a fluke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now fixed in version 12.2 of [`bidi` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) which is now on CTAN. Please for future, do not report `bidi` issues here; it is very hard for us to search Internet and hunt down who has got problem and who has not. Instead, please do as stated in [README file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bidi/README) of `bidi` package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it happens, but enclosing `\ref` in `\mbox` seems to cure the disease:

```
$\mbox{\ref{sec}}$
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the combination of `hyperref` and `bidi` doesn't like xrefs in math.  you can `\usepackage{amstext}` and then `\text{\ref{...}}`.